# How to use set scanset in sscanf to read numbers like 0-9

Tags: c, scanf

How to read the input with scanset like[0-9] or [a-z] in sscanf function in C.We have not been able to successfully implement a scanset to scan through a string successfully.

This is my example:

```
void printResult(char * test, char * actual, char * expected)
{
    printf("\n\n%d. %s\r",testcount++, test);

    if(strcmp(actual,expected) == 0)
{
    printf("SUCCESS\r");
    printf("Output:%s", actual);
}
else
{
    printf("FAILED\r");
    printf("Expected Output:%s   Actual Output:%s", expected, actual);
    }
    }
    int main()
  {
    char buffer[] = "250MEL\r";
    char * pBuffer = buffer;
    char output[5]={0};
    //1 
    sscanf(pBuffer,"%[ 0-9 ]s",output);
    printResult("%[0-9]s", output, "250");

    //2
    sscanf(pBuffer,"%3[ 0-9 ]s",output);
    printResult("%3[0-9]s", output, "250");


    return 0;
    }
```

can you anyone help me to use a scanset correctly.

Comment: Please indent your code properly :-)

Comment: @lotus "%3[ 0-9 ]s" remove the spaces: "%3[0-9]s"

Comment: Try `if (sscanf(pBuffer,"%4[0-9]",output) == 1)  printResult("%4[0-9]", output, "250");`

Comment: Explain more about `[a-z]`.  The one test case `"250MEL\r"` does not contain lower case letters.

Comment: Note that a scan set is `”%[…]”`; the `s` in the code in the question is not a part of the scan set and would only match and consume a literal `'s'` in the input; otherwise it fails silently because it is the last character of the format string.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** It isn't clear what makes you think your scan sets failed; they work OK in this context for me.  The mildly modified code shown below demonstrates this.

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117158/how-to-use-set-scanset-in-sscanf-to-read-numbers-like-0-9#comment91195608_52117158), a scan set is of the form `%[…]` — it stops at the `]` and anything following (`s` in the code in the question) is not part of the scan set.  If you need to include `]` in the scan set, it must be the first character (after the caret that negates a scan set, if you're using a negated scan set).  With the `s` after the scan set, if the input includes an `s` after the end of the digit and blank sequence (the first blank in the scan set is significant; the second, being a repeat, is not), then that character will be 'consumed' and the next input operation would continue after the `s`; if the next character is not an `s`, then it is left in the input for the next input operation.  Also, if the next character is not an `s`, the matching fails, but there is no way for `sscanf()` to report that when the scan set is the last or only conversion specification in the format string.  Trailing context is always expendable; it's absence cannot be detected.

Your code is curious in that it uses `\r` in a number of places.  You will seldom need to use `\r` in C code — you should use `\n` in your code (or blanks, or …).

Here's a program closely based on yours, with some changes.  The code checks the return value from `sscanf()`; it replaces most of the carriage returns with some other character(s); it keeps the faulty format strings; it makes the argument to the print function match the argument to the `sscanf()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int testcount = 1;

static void printResult(char *test, char *actual, char *expected)
{
    printf("\n\n%d. [%s]: ", testcount++, test);

    if (strcmp(actual, expected) == 0)
    {
        printf("SUCCESS  ");
        printf("Output: [%s]\n", actual);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAILED  ");
        printf("Expected Output: [%s], Actual Output: [%s]\n", expected, actual);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "250MEL\r";
    char *pBuffer = buffer;
    char output[5] = {0};
    // 1
    if (sscanf(pBuffer, "%[ 0-9 ]s", output) != 1)
        printf("scanf() 1 failed\n");
    printResult("%[ 0-9 ]s", output, "250");

    // 2
    if (sscanf(pBuffer, "%3[ 0-9 ]s", output) != 1)
        printf("scanf() 1 failed\n");
    printResult("%3[ 0-9 ]s", output, "250");

    return 0;
}
```

It also produces the expected output:

```
1. [%[ 0-9 ]s]: SUCCESS  Output: [250]


2. [%3[ 0-9 ]s]: SUCCESS  Output: [250]
```

If you weren't seeing `SUCCESS` before, that's because the `\r` character moves the writing position to the start of the line, so what followed overwrote `SUCCESS`.

#### Auxilliary question

> Also, please let me know how can I set a range for A-Z like below — but this is not working:
>
> ```
> sscanf(pBuffer,"%*[A-Z]s",output);
> printResult("%[A-Z]s",output, "MEL" );
> ```

Please *pay attention!*

Your comment is showing that you still think `%[…]s` is the notation for a scan set but the `s` is spurious; it is not part of the scan set notation. Stop thinking of `%[…]` as a modifier for `%s`; it isn't a modifier. It is a completely independent conversion specification, almost wholly unrelated to and syntactically quite distinct from `%s`. The square-bracket notation is also, categorically and unequivocally, not a part of any standard `printf()` conversion specification syntax.

Here is some revised code loosely based on the previous part of the answer (and hence on the code in the question).  It isn't stellar, but it does show some useful information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int strings_match(const char *actual, const char *expected);
static void printResult(const char *format, const char *data, const char *act1,
                        char *exp1, const char *act2, char *exp2);

int main(void)
{
    char buffer1[] = "250MEL@93";
    char buffer2[] = "  250   \t\tMELabc";
    char number[5] = "";
    char letters[5] = "";
    const char fmt1[] = "%4[0-9]%4[A-Z]";
    const char fmt2[] = " %4[0-9] %4[A-Z]";

    if (sscanf(buffer1, fmt1, number, letters) != 2)
        printf("sscanf() 1 failed\n");
    else
        printResult(fmt1, buffer1, number, "250", letters, "MEL");

    if (sscanf(buffer2, fmt2, number, letters) != 2)
        printf("sscanf() 2 failed\n");
    else
        printResult(fmt2, buffer2, number, "250", letters, "MEL");

    number[0] = '\0';
    letters[0] = '\0';
    if (sscanf(buffer2, fmt1, number, letters) != 2)
        printf("sscanf() 3 failed\n");
    else
        printResult(fmt2, buffer1, number, "250", letters, "MEL");

    const char fmt3[] = "%4[0-9]s%c";
    const char fmt4[] = "%4[0-9]%c";
    char buffer3[] = "9876sun";
    char buffer4[] = "9876moon";
    char letter;

    if (sscanf(buffer3, fmt3, number, &letter) != 2)
        printf("sscanf() 4 failed\n");
    else
        printf("Data [%s], Format [%s], Output [%s] %c\n", buffer3, fmt3, number, letter);

    if (sscanf(buffer3, fmt4, number, &letter) != 2)
        printf("sscanf() 5 failed\n");
    else
        printf("Data [%s], Format [%s], Output [%s] %c\n", buffer3, fmt4, number, letter);

    if (sscanf(buffer4, fmt3, number, &letter) != 2)
        printf("sscanf() 6 failed\n");
    else
        printf("Data [%s], Format [%s], Output [%s] %c\n", buffer4, fmt3, number, letter);

    return 0;
}

static int strings_match(const char *actual, const char *expected)
{
    int rc;
    if (strcmp(actual, expected) == 0)
    {
        rc = 1;
        printf(" Output: [%s]", actual);
    }
    else
    {
        rc = 0;
        printf(" Expected Output: [%s], Actual Output: [%s]", expected, actual);
    }
    return rc;
}

static int testcount = 1;

static void printResult(const char *format, const char *data, const char *act1,
                        char *exp1, const char *act2, char *exp2)
{
    printf("Format: %d. [%s] Data: [%s]", testcount++, format, data);
    int t1 = strings_match(act1, exp1);
    int t2 = strings_match(act2, exp2);

    if (t1 == 1 && t2 == 1)
        printf(" - SUCCESS\n");
    else
        printf(" - FAILED\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Format: 1. [%4[0-9]%4[A-Z]] Data: [250MEL@93] Output: [250] Output: [MEL] - SUCCESS
Format: 2. [ %4[0-9] %4[A-Z]] Data: [  250          MELabc] Output: [250] Output: [MEL] - SUCCESS
sscanf() 3 failed
Data [9876sun], Format [%4[0-9]s%c], Output [9876] u
Data [9876sun], Format [%4[0-9]%c], Output [9876] s
sscanf() 6 failed
```

Note how the last two successful conversion lines differ — the `s` in the format string is matched as a literal to the data, leaving `u` to be read into the character, compared with when there is no `s` in the format string and the character matches the `s`.  In contrast, when the format looks for an `s` and finds `m`, the overall `sscanf()` fails — it only manages 1 instead of 2 conversion specifications.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your extra question.